# What's wrong with this lua script

Tags: lua

```
RPS = {}
RPS[1] = "Rock"
RPS[2] = "Paper"
RPS[3] = "Scissors"
function RPS()
    playerOne = math.random( #RPS ) 
    playerTwo = math.random( #RPS )

    if playerOne == playerTwo then
        print("It is a tie\n Player One played "..playerOne.."\n Player Two played "..playerTwo..)
    elseif playerOne == RPS[1] then
        if playerTwo == RPS[2] then
            print("Player Two wins\n Player One played "..playerOne.."\n Player Two played "..playerTwo..)
        else
            print("Player One wins\n Player One played "..playerOne.."\n Player Two played "..playerTwo..)
        end
    elseif playerOne == RPS[2] then
        if playerTwo == RPS[1] then
            print("Player One wins\n Player One played "..playerOne.."\n Player Two played "..playerTwo..)
        else
            print("Player Two wins\n Player One played "..playerOne.."\n Player Two played "..playerTwo..)
        end
    else
        if playerTwo == RPS[1] then
            print("Player Two wins\n Player One played "..playerOne.."\n Player Two played "..playerTwo..)
        else
            print("Player One wins\n Player One played "..playerOne.."\n Player Two played "..playerTwo..)
        end
    end
end
print(RPS())
```

Don't know what's wrong with this script, appreciate some input from you guys. Although the error says on line 19:

```
    print("Player One wins\n Player One played "..playerOne.."\n Player Two played "..playerTwo..)
```

That there is an  expected near ')'

Comment: Meant to say "That there is an <expression> expected near ')'

Comment: In addition to the solution given below you'll want to either change the name of your function or table so they are not the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a concatenation call (`..`) at the end, but it only has one argument. Delete that and that should fix the error. Remember that concatenation means adding two strings together and it must have two arguments.

```
print("Player One wins\n Player One played "..playerOne.."\n Player Two played "..playerTwo)
```

You also need to change the table name or the function name since they are conflicting.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that but I am still getting an error "
[ERROR] lua/rps.lua:6: attempt to get length of global 'RPS' (a function value)
  1. RPS - lua/rps.lua:6
   2. unknown - lua/rps.lua:31"

Comment: Check out the comment below your post. You need to change the name of the function since it is conflicting with the table name.

Comment: Just to clarify, Lua values, such as tables and functions don't have names; Variables do. You are perfectly free to assign the variable RPS a table value and then a function value. The problem occurs because when the function runs, RPS references it and code treats it like it references a table.